# Ssh login success but it is not me

Tags: server, ssh, login, password, hacking

I receive ssh login alert from two different ip on my server

```
Time:    Fri Mar 22 05:50:37 2019 +0300
IP:      92.184.99.172 (FR/France/-)
Account: root
Method:  password authentication
```

second ip:

```
Time:    Fri Mar 22 05:50:37 2019 +0300
IP:      92.184.98.206 (FR/France/-)
Account: root
Method:  password authentication
```

I also change password and I also change ssh port.

I don’t understand because it is impossible.

I slept at night and it has already happened several times since 2 weeks. no page or terminal is open on my pc or my mobile. I do not understand.

My actual ip is not listed.

Comment: Steps I would do. Take the server offline. Create an ssh login key. Do **NOT** share the key with anybody. physically copy the key to the server. Disallow all password access

Comment: If you suspect anybody got unauthorized access to the system, you should nuke it from orbit and do a clean reinstall. You can't be sure that whoever got in didn't set up a backdoor or anything similar to secure their access even if you manage to fix the hole through which they got in.

Comment: it looks like you use cable and wifi same time.